# Raster Time Series, express years in time series

Tags: raster, r, datetime, time-series

What's the best option to express years in *Raster Time Series object* in R.
I define years as dates:

```
YEARSSEQ <-seq(as.Date("2008-01-01"), as.Date("2009-01-01"), "year")
```

and then I pass them in rts constructor function

```
myrts<-rts(myrasterstack,YEARSSEQ)
```

Passing  as

```
YEARSSEQ = c("2008", "2009")
```

returns the error

```
  time must be one of time-based classes including: 'POSIXct', 'POSIXt', 'Date', 'timeDate', 'yearmon','yearqtr'
```

Is there any better option?

Comment: You haven't defined anything as dates: all your examples are strings.  You need to convert the strings to some kind of date as explained by the error message.  You can do that directly with, say, `strptime` and `as.POSIXct`: the help page for the former is particularly useful.

Comment: Where does the `rts` function come from?

Comment: rts function comes from [Raster Time Series Analysis package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rts/rts.pdf).

Comment: Just place the right code about YEARSSEQ as dates.